# Cannot evaluate subset expression for N

Tags: model, compilation, subset, jags

I have been trying to run single season single species occupancy but R keeps on giving the error:

`Cannot evaluate subset expression for N`

I have attached the JAGS script herewith.

```
model{
  # Likelihood
  for(i in 1:nSites){
    # biological model
    logit(psi[i]) <- b0 + bHumans * hums[i] + 
        bElevation * ele[i] + bDD * dd[i] + bRuggedness * rugged[i] + bLivestock * livstck[i] + bVillage_dist * village[i]
    z[i] ~ dbern(psi[i])
    # observation model
    y[i] ~ dbin(p * z[i], n[i])
  }

  # Priors
  psi0 ~ dbeta(1, 1)
  b0 <- logit(psi0)
  bHumans ~ dunif(-5, 5)    # humans
  bElevation ~ dunif(-5, 5)   # elevation
  bDD ~ dunif(-5, 5)  # dd
  bRuggedness ~ dunif(-5,5) # rugg
  bLivestock ~ dunif(-5,5) #livestock
  bVillage_dist ~ dunif(-5,5) # village
  p ~ dbeta(1, 1)
  
  # Derived variable
  N <- sum(z)
}
```

Comment: This model looks correct so the issue is likely in the variables you supplied to the model. It seems like you have `n` as well as `N`, it could possibly be that you have some issue related to that with what you are using in your list of data you  supply to JAGS. Unfortunately, without a working example there isn't much else more help I can provide.

Comment: Hey Thanks. The issue is resolved :)